# Lost my terminal application in my desktop

Tags: gnome-terminal, .desktop, terminator

l was dealing with

`E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/`

then l don't know what l done so l lost my terminal and terminator and other desktop application (Pycharm , slack ...). even from `'search your computer'` .
l tried to print my screen to show that for you however it doesn(t work when l press on l get black screen.

What's wrong ? how can l repair it

```
edit1
ls /boot/
abi-4.4.0-71-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-4.4.0-72-generic         memtest86+.elf
config-4.4.0-71-generic      memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-4.4.0-72-generic      System.map-4.4.0-71-generic
efi                          System.map-4.4.0-72-generic
grub                         vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908318/e-you-dont-have-enough-free-space-in-var-cache-apt-archives)

Comment: @JacobVlijm, l lost my terminal application in my desktop

Comment: @vincent: your 25 GB `/dev/sda1` partition is 100% full. You have to delete no longer needed files. Likely it is old kernels. These have to be removed manually. If it is not the kernels you need to find out what else it might be.

Answer (score 1):

Your main disk is 100% full. Either use the `Disk Usage Analyzer` to observe where your disk space went, and to delete files, or boot into `Recovery mode` to use terminal commands to resolve your problem.

**Warning: DON'T delete any files if you don't know what they are, or what they do!**

First check the file system on your Ubuntu partition... then use other terminal commands to fix the problem...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /` # to check your file system for errors
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `df -h` # to see where your disk space has gone to zero
- use other terminal commands to delete unnecessary files to make more space in /

Comment: please see my update

Comment: @vincent /boot isn't where your problem is. If you use the `df -h` it'll tell you where the disk space used is 100%. Monitor what goes on in https://askubuntu.com/questions/908318/e-you-dont-have-enough-free-space-in-var-cache-apt-archives#908318 as they have a similar problem.